# Sharepoint Linked Table Problems when using Microsoft Access

Tags: microsoft-access, database-connection

So here is my situation. I have 2 sharepoint sites which I am currently a member of the "Owners" permission group:

1. https://mysite.sharepoint.com/     (root site, so I would like to avoid putting important data here)
2. https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/data

Using MS Access, I can successfully create/import/link sharepoint list on Sharepoint site #1, but I cannot do the same thing on #2. My method of creating connections is via Internet Explorer, logging into the site, and using the "Open with Access Button. I have already set "Manage site features" settings to be the same, same permission levels on both. I have also tested the "Export to Excel" with both sites and experienced similar problems. This might not be important but these are also Office 365 sharepoint sites.

Is there something else that I am missing as a Sharepoint administrator that allows #1 to work but not #2?

Thank you for any help you can provide me.